# Reuse select query in a procedure in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How would I store the result of a select statement so I can reuse the results with an `in` clause for other queries? Here's some pseudo code:

```
declare
  ids <type?>;
begin
  ids := select id from table_with_ids;
  select * from table1 where id in (ids);
  select * from table2 where id in (ids);
end;
```

... or will the optimizer do this for me if I simply put the sub-query in both select statements?

EDIT: Here's more information about the structure of my tables.

Basically table1 is a standard table with the id being the primary key. While table2 has a 3-column primary key with id being one of those columns. In my case the id in table2 will appear in three rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a SQL table object to store the result of the select and reuse it. It will consume more memory and will probably be efficient only if the first SELECT takes a lot of time.

```
CREATE TYPE tab_number IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/
```

You would use it with a BULK COLLECT INTO clause:

```
DECLARE
   ids tab_number;
BEGIN
   SELECT id BULK COLLECT INTO ids FROM table_with_ids;
   SELECT * /*into ??*/ 
     FROM table1 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(ids));
   SELECT * /*into ??*/ 
     FROM table2
    WHERE id IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(ids));
END;
```

In version 9i and before you would need to use CAST to query the table:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table2 
 WHERE id IN (SELECT column_value FROM CAST (TABLE(ids) AS tab_number));
```

Alternatively, you could use a [GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#sthref7483) to store the intermediate result set.