# Reuse of select query result oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got following query

```
SELECT ID FROM MARMELADES mrm 
where not exists 
    (SELECT 1 FROM TOYS toys 
    WHERE mrm.ID = toys.ID 
    AND mrm.INGREDIENT = toys.INGREDIENT 
    AND mrm.BOX_TYPE = 2)
AND mrm.BOX_TYPE = 2
```

It returns almost 400+ results of id, for example `[12, 33, 45, ... , 3405]`

Now, i want to remove all ids that are from that list everywhere from my database. this is not only MARMELADES and TOYS. Also, i have for example 35+ tables where i can have this id).

I would be happy if this query could extract in some functions like ALL_UNNEEDED_IDS so i can use it like this:

```
DELETE FROM ANOTHER_TABLE_1 WHERE ID IN ( ALL_UNNEEDED_IDS ) 
DELETE FROM ANOTHER_TABLE_2 WHERE ID IN ( ALL_UNNEEDED_IDS ) 
DELETE FROM ANOTHER_TABLE_3 WHERE ID IN ( ALL_UNNEEDED_IDS ) 
DELETE FROM ANOTHER_TABLE_4 WHERE ID IN ( ALL_UNNEEDED_IDS ) 
...
DELETE FROM ANOTHER_TABLE_35 WHERE ID IN ( ALL_UNNEEDED_IDS )
```

It is possible to do it in oracle to reuse such results?

Comment: Create a temporary table and store the unneeded ids there.

Comment: If all these tables are relaeted by this ID as an FK, sounds like you should configure them for cascading delete.  Otherwise, insert your query results into a temp table, then reference that from all the delete calls.

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119465/how-to-reuse-a-large-query-without-repeating-it

Comment: For Oracle:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501683/reuse-select-query-in-a-procedure-in-oracle

Comment: Using the Oracle solution @MathewsMathai mentioned, you don't even need to create a new type.  You can use an existing Oracle type such as `KU$_OBJNUMSET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first query within your subsequent queries. IE:

```
DELETE FROM ANOTHER_TABLE_1 WHERE ID IN (
     SELECT ID FROM MARMELADES mrm 
     where not exists 
         (SELECT 1 FROM TOYS toys 
         WHERE mrm.ID = toys.ID 
         AND mrm.INGREDIENT = toys.INGREDIENT 
         AND mrm.BOX_TYPE = 2)
     AND mrm.BOX_TYPE = 2
);
```

When you get to the toys and marmelades tables, you'll need a temporary holder table as @Gordon suggests.